# use on_success and on_failure methon in django-celery

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

I am using djcelery.
I have created one task.

```
@celery.decorators.periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=2))
def add(x, y):
    cont= 0
    print x
    print y
    for i in range(x, y):
        cont = cont+1
    return cont
```

i clalled it in view.py

```
def home(request):
    print "debug"
    st = add.delay(63,230)
    return  render(request, 'home/home.html', {})
```

now how can i detect the task is complete or failed.
i want to perform certain actions on success and failure.

Comment: [the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks) seem pretty clear on how to use this.

Comment: Actually, no, they aren't.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your use case, but one way would be to save a flag in memory (cache, database, etc) and update it accordingly.

To display any async updates frontend, create an endpoint to check the flag and poll it with ajax.

Comment: how to use on_succeed() and on_failure() method of class TaskEvent?